# Error when running LP Solve formula, Unsure how to add fraction

Tags: r, lpsolve

[Formula, Objective and Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zZ1V.png)

```
library(lpSolve)
obj.fun<-c(420,360,300,420,360,300,420,360,300)
constr<- 
matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,20,15,12,20,15,12,20,15,
12,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,.0013,-.001,
           .0013,-.002,
           nrow=11,byrow=TRUE))
constr.dir<-c("<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","=","=")
rhs<-c(750,900,450,13000,12000,5000,900,1200,750,0,0)
    
probsol<-lp("max",obj.fun,constr,constr.dir,rhs,compute.sens = TRUE)
probsol$solution
1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

This is my answer, but I know it's wrong, and I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second constraint has as coefficients 2, so shouldn’t your constraint matrix start with 1,1,1,2,2,2,…?

In order to add the last two constraints, you would need to manipulate the terms to derive the coefficients. For example, the last constraint becomes (1/750-3/450)x1+…

Also your objective function should have three components only.

Comment: Sorry, I updated with a picture to show formula, I entered it in wrong